# Enable CORS for war in Apache ServiceMix

Tags: java, angular, http, apache-camel, apache-servicemix

I am deploying an angular2 webapp in servicemix as a war file. This makes the app run on `localhost:8181/angular2webapp` url. I have a bundle installed for REST requests, which is basically a camel component.

```
<cxf:rsServer id="rsServer" address="http://localhost:9090"
    serviceClass="com.mypackage.class.MyClass" />
```

Now while using this angular2 app, I am getting

```
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8181' is therefore not allowed access.
```

I tried using `.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", constant("*"))` in my route but it doesn't seem to work.
Can anyone please help me out with this?

Answer (score 1):

See the CXF-RS documentation how to setup a CORS filter

- http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-cors.html

You need to add that to the xml stuff in that `rsServer`